# Printing random lines from a file and compiling it to WebAssembly for web view

Tags: rust, webassembly

I want to learn Wasm and Rust. This project can execute Wasm from GitHub Pages. The first attempts failed because of some policy error with the Wasm MIME type. When I tried [Yew Framework](https://github.com/yewstack/yew) then [it worked](https://montao.github.io/spooks-web/) to run Wasm for my first attempt (it just writes random rows from a text file).

For some reason I got a MIME type error when trying the [official example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Rust_to_wasm) from Mozilla and I want to be independent of node and npm whereas the official example requires npm (and would generate the MIME type error when deployed to GitHub Pages (but running as expected locally with the npm webpack)).

Here is my code done with yew framework. It is also in the [repository](https://github.com/montao/spooks-wasm-src).

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "spooks-wasm"
version = "0.1.1"
authors = ["Niklas <n*****@*****mail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
stdweb = "0.4.20"
getopts = "0.2"
rand = {version = "0.7", features = ['stdweb']}
easy_reader = "0.5.0"
yew = { path = "../.." }
```

**main.rs**

```
fn main() {
    yew::start_app::<counter::Model>();
}
```

**lib.rs**

```
#![recursion_limit = "128"]

extern crate easy_reader;
extern crate getopts;
extern crate rand;

use stdweb::web::Date;
use yew::services::ConsoleService;
use yew::{html, Component, ComponentLink, Html, ShouldRender};

use std::env;
use std::io::{Cursor, Error, Seek, SeekFrom, Write};
use crate::rand::Rng;

use easy_reader::EasyReader;
use getopts::Options;


pub struct Model {
    link: ComponentLink<Self>,
    console: ConsoleService,
    value: i64,
    spooks: String,
}

pub enum Msg {
    Increment,
    Decrement,
    Bulk(Vec<Msg>),
}

impl Component for Model {
    type Message = Msg;
    type Properties = ();

    fn create(_: Self::Properties, link: ComponentLink<Self>) -> Self {

        let mut c = Cursor::new(Vec::new());
        let str42 = include_str!("spook.lines").as_bytes();    

        // // Write into the "file" and seek to the beginning
        c.write_all(str42).unwrap();
        c.seek(SeekFrom::Start(0)).unwrap();

        let mut reader = EasyReader::new(c).unwrap();
        let _res = reader.build_index();
        let tmpspooks = reader.random_line().unwrap().unwrap() + &reader.random_line().unwrap().unwrap() + &reader.random_line().unwrap().unwrap() + &reader.random_line().unwrap().unwrap() + &reader.random_line().unwrap().unwrap();


        Model {
            link,
            console: ConsoleService::new(),
            value: 0,
            spooks: tmpspooks
        }
    }

    fn update(&mut self, msg: Self::Message) -> ShouldRender {        

        let mut c = Cursor::new(Vec::new());
        let str42 = include_str!("spook.lines").as_bytes();    

        // // Write into the "file" and seek to the beginning
        c.write_all(str42).unwrap();
        c.seek(SeekFrom::Start(0)).unwrap();

        let mut reader = EasyReader::new(c).unwrap();
        let _res = reader.build_index();
        self.spooks = reader.random_line().unwrap().unwrap() + &reader.random_line().unwrap().unwrap() + &reader.random_line().unwrap().unwrap() + &reader.random_line().unwrap().unwrap() + &reader.random_line().unwrap().unwrap();

        match msg {
            Msg::Increment => {
                self.value = self.value + 1;
                self.console.log("plus one");
            }
            Msg::Decrement => {
                self.value = self.value - 1;
                self.console.log("minus one");
            }
            Msg::Bulk(list) => {
                for msg in list {
                    self.update(msg);
                    self.console.log("Bulk action");
                }
            }
        }
        true
    }

    fn view(&self) -> Html {        
        html! {
            <div>
                <p>{ &self.spooks }</p>               
                <nav class="menu">
                <button onclick=self.link.callback(|_| Msg::Increment)>
                    { "Spook" }
                </button>
            </nav>
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```